# Typescript interface: Not all constituents of type 'string | (() => string)' are callable. Type 'string' has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects

```
interface ExampleType {
  [key: string]: string | (() => string);
}

const testObj: ExampleType = {
  firstName: "Peter",
  lastName: "Parker",
  gender: "male",
  getFullName: () => "I am Peter Parker",
};

const { firstName, lastName, getFullName } = testObj;


console.log(getFullName()); // this does  not works

if (typeof getFullName === "function") {
    console.log(getFullName()) // this works
}
```

I am getting following error:
**This expression is not callable.
Not all constituents of type 'string | (() => string)' are callable.
Type 'string' has no call signatures. **

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By saying `testObj: ExampleType`, you are saying that `testObj` will be an object in which the properties are either `string` or `() => string`. That's a broad, weak promise. However, you know exactly which properties will be of which kind.

**Solution one**

Tell the compiler everything you know. Include concrete property names in `ExampleType`.

```
interface ExampleType {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  gender: string;
  getFullName: () => string;
}

const testObj: ExampleType = {
  firstName: "Peter",
  lastName: "Parker",
  gender: "male",
  getFullName: () => "I am Peter Parker",
};

const { firstName, lastName, getFullName } = testObj;

console.log(getFullName()); // this works
```

**Solution two**

If you want to use `ExampleType` as a blueprint, but want the specific properties inferred for you, use a helper function like `specific` defined below.

```
interface ExampleType {
  [key: string]: string | (() => string);
}

const specific = <T>() => <U extends T>(argument: U) => argument;

const testObj = specific<ExampleType>()({
  firstName: "Peter",
  lastName: "Parker",
  gender: "male",
  getFullName: () => "I am Peter Parker",
});

const { firstName, lastName, getFullName } = testObj;

console.log(getFullName()); // this works
```

Comment: I cannot write types to specific properties as real objects contains multiple entries, unlike example object. But second solution works for me. Thanks!!